# how to go to tab bar controller after clicking the respective button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have structure of project as shown below.

[image]

On the left side I have MainViewController. There I have  two buttons as English and Arabic. What I want to do is when I click English, I want to go English tab bar controller (HomeViewController).

Hence what I wrote is

```
- (IBAction)langEnglish:(id)sender {
    HomeViewController *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"enghome"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

This is working perfectly, but I don't see tab bar.

Tab bar is missing from this.

Any idea what is going wrong?

---

**Basically what I have is view controller as main controller and upon clicking button on this controller, tab view controller should get open...**

Comment: The code you show should work. In the line before you do the push, try logging secondView's class -- NSLog(@"%@",[secondView class]). What does it give?

Comment: @rdelmar : I got solution... i will post shortly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is as below

```
- (IBAction)langEnglish:(id)sender {
    EngTabViewController *secondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"engtab"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

EngTabViewController is the UITabBarController and I assigned id to tab bar controller... this works like charm...

Means instead of viewcontorller, I used tabbarcontroller...

Answer (score 3):

Go to your main storyboard and select your main view controller. On top select Editor->Embed in->navigation bar.

**EDIT:** If this does not work push to your tab bar and use this code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Comment: if you see image, I already have navigation bar before mainviewcontroller... regarding `self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;` it there... the problem is I don't see tab bar...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't push a UITabBarController on a UINavigationController. Set it as the window's root view controller instead and the tab bar should be displayed as expected.

Comment: I do understand but first screen should be homeviewcontroller to select language.. then I will go with tab bar controller...